# C# WPF UI is not updated by datatrigger when I change a property in the listview item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listviewitem, datatrigger

I want to make a chess game in WPF, I decided to use listview to display my fields. I have a class named Field with properties. I have a list containing 64 fields and i changed to style of my listview in xaml so its look like a chess field. However, i have problem with the datatriggers. I need to change the picture (that will show the chess piece) when a property in that element in my list is changed.Nothing happens when the 'hasPiece' property is changed. I use INotifyPropertyChanged so i think i have no problem with the UI refresh, because i can update any displayed data in labels and testboxs. That is why i know i successfully changed the property when i selected 1 item, because i binded to a label. So when i select a field(an item) the 'hasPiece' property is updated to hidden, but the image still remains visible. I dont know much about datatriggers and I dont know what i did wrong.

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"   ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" Width="410"  SelectedItem="{Binding selectedField,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value> 
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="4,4,4,4" Background="{Binding Brush}" BorderBrush="{Binding Brush}">
                                <Grid Name="Grid" Background="{Binding Brush}">
                                    <Image Name="PieceImage"  Height="40" Width="40" Source="Images/something.jpg" >
                                        
                                    </Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="{Binding MouseOverBrush}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding MouseOverBrush}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                 
                                </Trigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding hasPiece}" Value="Hidden">
                                    <Setter TargetName="PieceImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
                                        
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                    
                    
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This is what i currently do when an item is selected:

```
private Field selected { get; set; }
        public Field selectedField
        {
            get { return selected; }
            set
            {
                selected = value;
              //  fieldId = selected.ID.ToString();
                removeImage(selected.ID);
            }
        }
     

     public void removeImage(int id)
    {
        foreach (Field item in Fields)
        {
         
            if (item.ID == id)
            {
                
                item.hasPiece = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                fieldId = item.hasPiece.ToString();
               
            }
        }
    }
```

I currently just want to test everything that needed, i know later i have to change things, but now i just want to know how i can change something in the style with datatriggers properly.

Comment: How does your 'Field' type look?

Comment: @OneBigQuestion Im on mobile now, so i cant copy paste, but it has an id(int), two brushes which are binded as you can see and a hasPiece property which is a visibility. I may change and add things later, but now i just want to know how to use a datatrigger for that picture which is inside the template setter

Comment: Are you sure that `Value="Hidden"` is correct for a DataTrigger on your `hasPiece` property? The name strongly suggests a boolean property.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!

I implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to my **ViewModel**, so the **UI got updated** when a **variable which was created there is changed** or when I **added or removed items to my Observable collection** which was also created there.
However if I want to edit my collection I have to implement this interface to my **model**.
My problem was not related to `DataTrigger`. My problem was the lack of `INotifypropertyChanged` in my model.